# Trapezium rule: undefined values of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I am trying to estimate the area between the curve $f(x) = \frac {\sin(x)}{x^2+2x}$ and the $x$ axis between $x=-1$ and $x=2$ using the trapezium with $6$ strips.

However, when calculating values for $f(0)$ we obtain undefined values. How should I proceed from here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin x}x \times \frac1{x+2}
$$ you may extend $f$, by continuity, making $x \to 0$, with

> $$
> f(0)=1\times \frac1{0+2}=\frac12.
> $$

I don't see any problem with your initial function at $x=2$:

> $$
> f(2)=\frac{\sin 2}{2^2+2\times2}=\frac{\sin 2}8.
> $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry, I'll amend that

Comment: @AlexanderMilanovic You are welcome. Thanks!